# Calculate new point of first line based on angle and starting point of second line?

Tags: math

I have two lines intersecting with each other at a certain point let's say (X2, Y2), and angle = 78. For example Line1 Starting point : (x1,y1) and Line1 Ending Point : (X2, Y2). Same way Line2 starting point (X3,y3) and Line2 Ending point : (X2, Y2).
**Now I want to change the position of two lines intersection point (X2, Y2) in a way that angle = 95 (Diagram#2 in below image)**.
(X1, Y1) and (X3, Y3) needs to remain the same.

[image]

Comment: that seems much more of a pure _math_ question than a programming question related to any of the two _very different_ languages you tagged.

Comment: also: 
seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269050/finding-the-angle-between-two-line-equations/

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i have tried so many solution but nothing is working for me. I need to change (X2, Y2) based on given angle value as a input from user.  If user enters angle = 125 then (X2, Y2) should be moved in a way that angle between two lines will be 125.

Comment: Added C++ tag because i have to implement above login in C++

Comment: @SagarPatel that might be, but your question does not show _any_ attempt or how exactly it didn't work.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I did google and I didn't find any solution which shows how to change line intersecting point based on input angle value between two lines. All the solutions I found rely on only a single line which does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should add another constraint if you want an unique solution. For example, let's assume that (X1,Y1) = (0,0) and (X3,Y3)=(10,10). Starting with (X2,Y2)=(10,0). If you move X2 to 5 you will have an angle of 112,5°. But if you want that specific angle you could move (X2,Y2) to (10,5) and still maintain that angle. You might add a constraint to a single coordinate, like keeping Y2=0.
By doing so you just have to get the angle based on the distance between X2 and X2', and reverse the formula, so you get how much you should move X2 to have your desired angle, maintaining the same abscissa.

Comment: Can you give me a code implementation?

Comment: Based on? What data do you have? What language are you using? Which constraint will you follow?

Comment: I am using C++. The only Constraint is that two lines intersecting points need to be changed based on the given angle between two lines.

Comment: You have an infinite amount of combination of X2,Y2 in which your request is fulfilled. In order to get ONE and only result you need to apply an additional constrain

Comment: If I say clockwise or anticlockwise then?